# Updating scope inside directive and preventing Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angularjs-scope, directive

I'm trying to change scope data inside directive and I'm getting thi Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress. 
I tried with $timeout but it did not help. 
I'm iterating through categories array and displaying breadcrumbs (e.g. something1 > something2 > something3 > something4) which are contained as string in category.name.

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
       <div breadcrumbs="breadcrumbs" category="category">
        <span class="description" id="name_{{category.id}}" >{{category.name}}</span>
       <div>
</div>
```

I want that when the container of this div is shrinked that breadcrumbs responsively change into this form 'something1 > ... > something3  > something4' or this 'something1>...>something4' depending how wide container is and how long breadcrumbs are.

To make that happen I have created directive called 'breadcrumbs' which is checking if the size of the related element is bigger than 20 it means breadcrumb has to be shrinken.
Here is directive..

```
angular.module('demo')
.directive('breadcrumbs', [ '$log', '$window', function($log, $window) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ){
                scope.getElemHeight = function() {
                    return elem.height();
                }

                scope.shortenBreadcrumb  = function(){
                    if (scope.getElemHeight() > 20){  
                        console.log(scope.getElemHeight());
                         var breadcrumbArry = scope.category.name.split(" > ");
                         var i = 1;
                 //remove breadcrumb by breadcrumb until whole breadcrumbs string fits the container
                 while ((scope.getElemHeight() > 20) && (breadcrumbArry.length > 3)){
                            if (i == 1) breadcrumbArry[i] = "..."
                            else breadcrumbArry.splice(2, 1); // remove 1 element on index 2
                            scope.category.name = breadcrumbArry.join(" > ");
                            i++;
                            scope.$apply();
                 }
                    }

                }

                // Set on load
                scope.$watch(scope.getElemHeight, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.shortenBreadcrumb();
                    console.log("LOOOOOOAD "+scope.category.id);
                }, true);

                // Set on resize
                angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
                    scope.category.name = scope.category.fullBreadcrumb;
                    scope.shortenBreadcrumb();
                    scope.$apply();

                });                 
        },  
        scope: {
            category: '='
        }
    }
}]);
```

It works well on load and on window resize but I'm keep getting mentioned error on the console. I have tried with $timeout inside while loop but I then my browser crashes because it waits forever and never enters timeout function probably because it is called from the $scope.watch. 
I'm really need help with this because I have no ideas how to solve it.

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/radiolaria/0btwgmzj/29/  If you check console output you'll see error.

Comment: most probable culprit is $watch, also your syntax for $watch is incorrect...

Comment: Ok when I remove 'true' from watch it's the same..What else would you suggest? How to approach this problem?

Comment: try removing the while loop...

Comment: I tried. It does not help and I need it because in each while loop I'm removing one breadcrumb until whole breadcrumbs expression fits the window.

Comment: I have also added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/radiolaria/0btwgmzj/29/ with existing situation

Answer (score 0):

remove both `$scope.$apply` call, and replace calls to shorten-bread-crumb with `scope.$evalAsync(scope.shortenBreadcrumb);`